# Public Chatrooms dedicated to personal further discussions

Tags: discussion, chat

I have recently started a few comment discussions that got off-topic rather quick, happily there is the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/) for that!

Although after the searching I did, I could not find out if it is forbidden or allowed to create a room solely for the purpose to continue discussions started by one self and maintain this as a "personal chat" for public discussions.

I am aware Stack Exchange suggests creating a chat room whenever a comment discussion gets "out of hand", but I'd like to maintain a personal channel that can be reused and move discussions out of the comment section beforehand. (I know I will surely start more some off-topic conversations `:P`)

Comment: Please do not discriminate "I"s. They have all the right to be capitalized.

Comment: Haha, **I** am sorry, english is not my native language and the `i`'s are not capitalized in german mid-sentence, so **I** tend to forget to capitalize those ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can.

As far as I know, there are no rules against starting your own chat room(s).

As long as the contents of the room are not violating SE [Content Policy](https://stackexchange.com/legal/content-policy) (which also applies to chat), all is good and you can even have some fun and chat games.

Comment: Thank you, going to create a chat room for `fun and games :)`

Answer (score 2):

Moving the comments "beforehand" or whenever you want is only possible for mods. Also you can't choose where to move the comments  each time the comments discussion gets lengthy (or, again, beforehand), or can't move the comments every time in the same room (though you can flag your post to get the comments moved by a mod).

You can though create your own chatroom and invite there everyone you want to discuss something that was going to be discussed in the comments.

Comment: That is exactly what i want to do, or better said doing now, i think you misinterpreted what i meant with "move discussions out of the comment section beforehand".

Comment: @Tarekis What you're doing now? Creating your chatrooms? Why the question then?

Comment: It was more of an abbreviation of "inviting other users into a personal chat to prevent further discussion in the comment section", but thank you for your explanation.

Comment: Yes, i am now creating a chatroom for this purpose as Shadow Wizard [explained to me](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272742/311885) i am allowed to use chat for this purpose.